# Shopify POS for rental services

Tags: shopify

I want to know if Shopify POS allows selling of service through the POS? 
Specifically speaking if the POS will be used in a computer laboratory rental whereas:

- A customer walks in the store the cashier inputs time-in
- Cashier inputs time-out then POS calculates total hours and total cost of the service.

Is this possible with Shopify POS?

Answer (score 1):

You could set this up with a simple Shopify App. When the order is booked the App registers the time at the POS and the item is marked OUT. When the item is returned the POS user finds the order and marks the item as IN. Now the hours out are known. So apply those hours as a number of units (hours) and using a unit price (cost per hour), the order would be worth X. If it was nothing but a draft order, at that point it could be turned into a real order in exchange for the money.

You're welcome...